# Zoomable sunburst visualization comes out messed up

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram, tabletop.js

I am reading a spreadsheet using sheetsee.js (and tabletop.js) and trying to create a zoomable sunburst with labels visualization. However, it is only creating one level and the text is rotated either +90 or -90. The URL to my html page is http://www.wyzpubs.com/dataviz/sheetsee/dita_users_sb.html

Can someone tell me what could be causing this? I think the way I am creating the JSON with size information is OK and it is exactly like in metmajer's zoomable sunburst with labels.

Thanks,
Jayaram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is here in sheetsee.sunburst.js

```
var partition = d3.layout.partition()
        .value(function(d) { return d.size; });
```

Your data has nothing like size(in the json) thus everything gets collapsed.

It should have been some value to decide the arc length size
I did something like this(but you can change it to some biz logic of yours):

```
var partition = d3.layout.partition()
        .value(function(d) { return d.parent.children.length; });
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PoNjfzkZhJFvYFGEQBf4?p=preview)

Hope this helps!